# What happens when reassigning to a future that is not ready yet

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, future

During a code review, I came across a piece of code that basically boils down to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main( int, char ** )
{
    std::atomic<int> x( 0 );
    std::future<void> task;
    for( std::size_t i = 0u; i < 5u; ++i )
    {
        task = std::async( std::launch::async, [&x, i](){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 2u * ( 5u - i ) ) );
                ++x;
            } );
    }

    task.get();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was not quite sure whether

- it is guaranteed that all tasks are executed when printing out the result,
- whether the tasks would be executed one after another (i.e. the task assignment would be blocking) or not.

I could not answer that question from reading documentation on the internet, so I thought I would write the snippet above to find out what our compiler actually does.

Now, I found out that the answer of what gcc-5 does is indecisive and that made me even more curious: One would assume that the assignment is either blocking or non-blocking.

If it is blocking, the time taken by the program should basically be the sum of the time the individual tasks take to execute. The first one takes 10 seconds, the second 8, the third 6, the fourth 4 and the last 2 seconds. So in total it should take 10+8+6+4+2 = **30 seconds**.

If it is non-blocking, it should take as long as the last task, i.e. **2 seconds**.

Here is what happens: It takes **18 seconds** (measured using time ./a.out or a good old clock). By playing around a bit with the code I found out that the code behaves as if the assignment would be alternatingly blocking and non-blocking.

But this can't be true, right? `std::async` probably falls back to `std::deferred` half of the time? My debugger says that it spawns two threads, blocks until both threads exit, then spawns two more threads and so on.

What does the standard say? What should happen? What happens inside gcc-5?

Comment: The fact that the code does not take the expected amount of time to complete is strange, but what **is really strange** to me is that the value of `x` is correctly assigned 5, while the `sleep` are clearly not complete...

Comment: You should really print the elapsed time after the `sleep` calls in your lambda because you would be very surprised I think!

Comment: @Holt The `gcc` implementation is blocking *sometimes*, it all works out in this case, but may go wrong in other cases. I took a look at it in the debugger: 0 starts, 1 starts, 1 exits, 0 exits, 2 starts, 3 starts, 3 exits, 2 exits, 4 starts, 4 exits.

Comment: I did some testing and I think that what gcc does is the following: It uses two different threads, and alternate the creation of async on one thread or the other, and of course it will block if the chosen thread is already performing something. In your case: 1 starts on thread A, 2 starts on thread B (concurrent with 1), 3 starts on thread A after 1, 4 starts on thread B after 2, 5 starts on thread A after 3, so the total execution time is max(10 + 6 + 2, 8 + 4) which is 18 as you see. I found the above by outputing `this_tread::get_id` in the lambda.

Comment: @Holt Yes, this could be the case, but I was not satisfied with this explanation for two reasons: First, the debugger reports that threads are created and exited, they also get new LWPs, just the thread ids remain the same, so I think that std::async actually creates threads and the ids are reused. Second, when I change the example to use 5 different futures, 5 threads run concurrently and the behaviour of std::async should not be affected by its return value.

Comment: My digging was more for me to understand well what was going on than to provide a concrete explanation - Actually, I think I now found the right explanation for why you get 18 seconds while (as I would assume) **all** move are blocking (see the end of my answer).

Comment: @Holt That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, the assignments of `task` via `operator=(&&)` do not have to be blocking (see below), but since you created the `std::future` using `std::async`, these assignments become blocking (thanks to @T.C.):

[[future.async]](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.async#5)

> If the implementation chooses the launch::async policy,
>
> - [...]
> - the associated thread completion synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the return from the first function that successfully detects the ready status of the shared state or with **the return from the last function that releases the shared state**, whichever happens first.

## Why do you get a 18 seconds execution time?

What happens in your case is that `std::async` starts the "thread" for your lambda **before** the assignment — See below for a detailed explanation on how you get an execution time of 18 seconds.

This is what (probably) happens in your code (`e` stands for an epsilon):

- `t = 0`, first `std::async` call with `i = 0`, starting a new thread;
- `t = 0 + e`, second `std::async` call with `i = 1` starting a new thread, then move. The move will release the current *shared state* of `task`, blocking for about 10 seconds (but the second `std::async` with `i = 1` is already executing);
- `t = 10`, third `std::async` call with `i = 2` starting a new thread, then move. The current *shared state* of `task` was the call with `i = 1` which is already ready so nothing blocks;
- `t = 10 + e`, fourth `std::async` call with `i = 3` starting a new thread, then move. The move is blocking because the previous `std::async` with `i = 2` is not ready but the thread for `i = 3` as already started;
- `t = 16`, fifth `std::async` call with `i = 4` starting a new thread, then move. The current *shared state* of `task` (`i = 3`) is already ready, so non-blocking;
- `t = 16 + e`, out of the loops, call to `.get()` wait for the *shared state` to be ready;
- `t = 18`, *shared state* becomes ready so the whole stuff ends.

## Standard details on `std::future::operator=`:

Here is the standard quote for `operator=` on `std::future`:

> ```
> future& operator=(future&& rhs) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects:*
>
> - (10.1) — releases any shared state (30.6.4).
> - ...

And here is what *"Releases any shared state"* mean (emphasis is mine):

> When an asynchronous return object or an asynchronous provider is said to release its shared state, it means:
>
> (5.1) — [...]
>
> (5.2) — [...]
>
> (5.3) — these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it **may block** if all of the following are true: **the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet
>   ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state**.

Your case fall into what I emphasized (I think). Your created the shared state using `std::async`, it is sleeping (so not ready) and you have only one reference to it, so this **may** be blocking.

Comment: [`async`'s specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.async#5) ensures that it will block. ("the associated thread completion synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the return from the first function that successfully detects the ready status of the shared state or with the return from the last function that releases the shared state, whichever happens first.")

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I was pretty sure that `std::future` created with `std::async` were blocking (probably saw this on SO some days) but I could not find the correct quote in the standard so I wrongly assumed that they may simply block. I have updated the answer with the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: Using VS2015 I instrumented the code and your proposition of what occurs is exactly correct ("on my compiler"). Of course, creating `task` as `tasks[5]`  allows all tasks to run in parallel (yielding net wait of 10 seconds - the longest task).

Comment: It's funny that the most useful text in the entire page is a comment. It's very counter-intuitive to guess that a reassignment may block indefinitely (and the spec is hard to read there) though one could think of it as "if it didn't block it would have to either have undefined behavior or add extra overhead to manage a problem".

Answer (score 4):

> it is guaranteed that all tasks are executed when printing out the result,

Only the task assigned last is guaranteed to have been executed. At least, I couldn't find any rules that would guarantee the rest.

> whether the tasks would be executed one after another (i.e. the task assignment would be blocking) or not.

Task assignment is generally non-blocking, but it may block in this case - with no guarantee.

[[futures.unique_future]](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures#futures.unique_future-10)

> future& operator=(future&& rhs) noexcept;
>
> 10. Effects:
>
>     releases any shared state ([futures.state]).

[[futures.state]](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.state#5)

> 5. When an asynchronous return object or an asynchronous provider is said to release its shared state, it means:
>
>    - if the return object or provider holds the last reference to its shared state, the shared state is destroyed; and
>    - the return object or provider gives up its reference to its shared state; and
>    - these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that **it may block** if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

All of the conditions for potential blocking are true of the task created by `std::async` hadn't executed yet.

Comment: Ah, *may block*, did not read this carefully, so basically the standard neither guarantees that it is blocking nor that it is non-blocking, right?

Comment: @MarkusMayr in this case, it would appear exactly so. I suppose this means that it falls into category of implementation defined behaviour.